# SSIS packages to import Excel Files into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, excel, import, dts

We have a number of import jobs that previously worked fine. These dtx packages were execute from VS2005 on a Windows XP box with Office 2007 installed.

The developer has not got a nice new machine, 64bit, Windows 7, Office 2010. Now when he tries to execute the packages he gets the following error:

> SSIS package
>   "Import_BygningsKategorier.dtsx"
>   starting. Information: 0x4004300A at
>   Data Flow - Import_BygningsKategorier,
>   DTS.Pipeline: Validation phase is
>   beginning. Error: 0xC0202009 at
>   Import_BygningsKategorier, Connection
>   manager "Excel Connection Manager":
>   SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An
>   OLE DB error has occurred. Error code:
>   0x80040154. An OLE DB record is
>   available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB
>   Service Components"  Hresult:
>   0x80040154  Description: "Class not
>   registered". Error: 0xC020801C at Data
>   Flow - Import_BygningsKategorier,
>   Source - Import_BygningsKategorier
>   [1]: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.
>   The AcquireConnection method call to
>   the connection manager "Excel
>   Connection Manager" failed with error
>   code 0xC0202009.  There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more
>   information on why the
>   AcquireConnection method call failed.
>   Error: 0xC0047017 at Data Flow -
>   Import_BygningsKategorier,
>   DTS.Pipeline: component "Source -
>   Import_BygningsKategorier" (1) failed
>   validation and returned error code
>   0xC020801C. Error: 0xC004700C at Data
>   Flow - Import_BygningsKategorier,
>   DTS.Pipeline: One or more component
>   failed validation. Error: 0xC0024107
>   at Data Flow -
>   Import_BygningsKategorier: There were
>   errors during task validation. SSIS
>   package
>   "Import_BygningsKategorier.dtsx"
>   finished: Failure. The program '[6332]
>   Import_BygningsKategorier.dtsx: DTS'
>   has exited with code 0 (0x0).

It looks like the problem may be that a class is not registered, how do we findout which class is not registered?

Comment: "The developer has *not* got a nice new machine" -- that is probably why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OLEDB drivers for Excel do not exist for 64 bit.

Run the 32-bit version of the DTS import utility (should be included, look in the Start menu).

Comment: Thanks, it was related to 64bit, we had to set the properties of the project to Use64bitRuntime=false